# Inserting into a table from an incompatible table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table called Person, and one day I accidentally deleted someone from this table. I have a backup table, called PersonBak so I was going to restore my deletion from the backup.  However, in the course of moving forward on my application I renamed all the fields in Person, except for the primary key, PersonID.  Now Person and PersonBak have the same data, but only one matching column name.

Is there any way to restore my missing person to Person from PersonBak without doing a lot of work? I have quite a few columns.  Of course I could just do the work now, but I can imagine this coming up again.

Is there some way to tell MySql that these are really the same table, with the columns in the same order, just different column names?  Or any way at all to do this without writing out specifics of which columns in PersonBak match which ones in Person?

Comment: _without doing a lot of work?_ - probably not.

Comment: @Mike Well, I can always hope.  There's so much out there, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column datatypes are the same between the tables, the column count is the same,  and they are all in the same order, then MySQL will do all of the work for you:

```
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2;
```

The column names are ignored.  The server uses ordinal position only, to decide how to line up the from/to columns.

Comment: good point - think we were all assuming there were more changes than that, but she didn't actually say there were, only col renames

Comment: Yes, that is EXACTLY what I was hoping I could do.  Yes, jmadsen, there were no changes whatever except for the column renames.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

> `insert into Person(id, col11, col12) (select id, col21, col22 from personBak where id=5)`

---

> person schema:
>
> `columns (id, col11, col12)`

---

> personBak schema:
>
> `columns (id, col21, col22)`

Comment: Anyway, easier that using the MySQl set to specify the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Mysql SELECT INTO and you can specify the field names & create an insert statement

Comment: Specifying the fieldnames is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You will have to specify the column/field names because you have renamed them.  If you think it will happen more often you might want to save the SQL script or create a view that aliases all the fields in the PersonBak so that it matches the Person table.

Comment: yes, or just rename your PersonBak. There is no "Computer - act on my thoughts" function in Mysql, although I agree there should be :-)

Comment: a last note - it's not much of a backup system if you don't have a backup that easily restores. you should consider improving on it

Comment: @Dijkgraaf -- creating a view is closer to what I had in mind.

Comment: @jmadsen You're darned right.  I want a command that says, do what I intended, not what I said.